# Regex for API documentation comments

Tags: regex

Is there a regex for comments that look like this:

```
/**
 * -string- (possible line) 
-possibly more lines like the above one-
 */
```

For example:

```
/**
 * The Boring class implements this and that
 * and also...
 * does this and that
 */
```

Comment: Which language are you using? Regex is not the same in every langauge.

Answer (score 5):

A simple `/\*\*.*?\*/` with a dotall (dot matches all) flag should do the trick. Although it may require different escaping or possible delimiters depending on which flavour of regex engine you're using.

If you don't have dotall in your engine try something like:

```
/\*\*[\s\S]*?\*/
```

Comment: May also need to be explictly set as "multiline" if the language supports it

Comment: Might need to explicitly exclude the trailing */ with `\/\*\*^(\*\/)*?\*\/`, also you're missing an escape before the last slash.

Comment: The first one doesn't work (with multiline), the second one works

Comment: @Hans I don't mean to escape any `/`. That's only necessary if `/` is picked as a delimiter and the engine requires delimiters, otherwise `/` has no special meaning. Since the question didn't specify I had to make some assumptions in my answer :)

Comment: @cookya Glad you got one to work :) `[\s\S]` means any character that is either whitespace or not whitespace (which is a long-winded way of saying any character).

Comment: It's not *multiline* mode you need, it's **single-line** or **DOTALL** mode; that's the one that allows the `.` (dot) to match newlines.  Ruby is the only flavor that (mistakenly) calls that mode *multiline*.  ECMAScript (which includes JavaScript, VBScript, and ActionScript) lacks such a mode entirely, so that's where you have to use `[\s\S]` or equivalent.